# How to use sonarqube permission template regexp

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I have the following sonar projet:

```
projectKey=com.domain.module.dev-tools.map-to-css-modules
projectName=com.domain.module.dev-tools.map-to-css-modules
```

I have created in sonarqube the following permissions template

```
name=dev-tools
description=
regexp=^com\.domain\.module\.dev-tools\.[A-z0-9-\.]+
```

I excpect this permissions template to be applied to any new project scanned that validate the regexp but I have to apply the permissions manually.

Does anybody know the correct synthax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work like that :

```
name=dev-tools
description=
regexp=com\.domain\.module\.dev-tools\..+
```

That's the way we're using it in Sonarqube 5.6.6 and it works fine.